# How can I know which columns in my table are considered unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two columns in my table which are unique: username and email. I'm trying to create a method which will automatically check if whatever the user inputs is unique or not. It's something like

```
def check_if_taken(arg = {})
  params.each do |key, value|
    if (key is a unique column???)
      return true if User.where(key => value).present?
    end
  end
  false
end
```

How do I figure out the unique columns in the table?

Edit: refactored

```
  def self.is_taken?(params = {})
    params.detect do |key, value|
      User.where(key => value).present?
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can't you use validation for this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say validation? We have validation constraint in the user model. In the JS/front-end, I'm using parsleyjs to validate the form. User types into the "username" field, we check db if username already exists. User types into the email field, we check db if email already exists.

Comment: You can use the `exists?` method. E.g: Model.exists(key: value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sth like:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base 
  def self.unique_attribute?(attribute_name)
    !!_validators[attribute_name] && !!_validators[attribute_name].find {|v| v.is_a? ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator)
  end
end
```

And then:

```
YourModel.unique_attribute?(attribute_to_check)
```